# backbone.js override contstructor

Tags: javascript, html, constructor, backbone.js

I'm building an html page that uses backbone.js

How can I override the constructor of a backbone Model?

Let me explain with an example:
I have a 2 models, let say M1, and M2.
In M2 constructor, I want to put and M1

```
m1=new M1({somedata:""});
m2=new M2({m1Ref: m1)
```

If I do this m2 will contain a reference to m1.
However what I need is m2 to have m1 data copied (somedata attribute value should be copied to m2), so I've tried to overwrite the constructor, and change the data received there

```
var M2=Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function(data){
    data=_.extend(data, data.timmer);
    data.timmer=undefined;
    Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.call(this, data);
  }
}
```

But this is not working properly.

How should override the constructor properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found the solution.

```
var M2=Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function(data, opts){

    data=_.extend(data, data.m1Ref);
    data.m1Ref=undefined;

    //new: we don't want to copy the id from m1 to m2
    data.id=undefined;

    Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.call(this, data);
  }
}
```